# sql server database object type to get all the constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

what is the `sql server` database object type to check for constraint (include all the constrains)?

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE IN (N'type_to_include_all_constraints')
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the more focused catalog views, instead of fiddling around with `sys.objects` and having to know all those types.

For check constraints, use

```
  SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints
```

For default constraints, use

```
  SELECT * FROM sys.default_constraints
```

See the [MSDN documentation on the catalog views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) for a complete list of all available catalog views in the `sys` schema, and what they contain.